# Passing struct variables between functions

Tags: c++, function, struct

i just have a quick question. i'm trying to make a vector addition program with some functions, but when i run it quick to check the numbers the output is still 0.

```
void input(struct vectors v1, struct vectors v2);
void addition (struct vectors  v1, struct  vectors v2);

struct vectors {
  int x;
  int y;
  }v1, v2;

  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    input(v1, v2);
    addition(v1, v2);
  }


  void input(struct vectors v1,struct vectors v2){

    cout << "Input x and y componenets of vector 1" << endl;
    cin >> v1.x;
    cin >> v1.y;
    cout << "Input x and y componenets of vector 2" << endl;
    cin >> v2.x;
    cin >> v2.y;

  }

  void addition ( vectors v1,  vectors  v2){

    int xsum = v1.x +v2.x;
    int ysum = v1.y +v2.y;

    cout << "sum of the x variables is " << xsum << endl << "sum of the y variables is " << ysum <<endl;

  }
```

Comment: C++ is pass by value. You have written your code as if it were pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `input`, you are modifying only a copy of the input argument. To see the changes visible in the calling function, pass the arguments by reference.

```
void input(struct vectors& v1,struct vectors& v2){

    cout << "Input x and y componenets of vector 1" << endl;
    cin >> v1.x;
    cin >> v1.y;
    cout << "Input x and y componenets of vector 2" << endl;
    cin >> v2.x;
    cin >> v2.y;

}
```

Also, since you are using `C++`, you can just use:

```
void input(vectors& v1, vectors& v2){
```

Comment: Thanks but when i do that i get a linker error. Im guessing i should change the functions call, but can you help me to what?

Comment: Change the declaration to match the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are passing the structs by value, so when you call the function, a copy of the struct is made, and in the function you are only modifying the copy. Instead, pass by reference:

```
void input( vectors& v1, vectors& v2 ) {
```

Also, in the other function, to avoid making an unnecessary copy, you can pass the structs by constant reference:

```
void addition( const vectors& v1, const vectors& v2 ) {
```